# Populate Listbox with Access Database?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm unable to get the listbox display values from my database.This is the code. ANy thoughts on how to crack it?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim strInsert As String
    Dim dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source =atg.mdb"
    Dim dtATG As DataTable

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dtTest As New DataTable
        dtTest.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(Integer))


        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            dtTest.Rows.Add(i, "Row " & i.ToString)
        Next

        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Col1"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "Col1"
        ListBox1.DataSource = dtTest.DefaultView
    AddHandler ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Yes! You will be able to do all of that using Visual Studio and VB .NET

Comment: @Ranhiru - I tried using the above code but haven't got any desired desults. Any links or tips on how to do it? (I have just tried to display the values form the DB to my listbox)

Comment: You add only 1 column, but by calling `dtTest.Rows.Add(i, "Row " & i.ToString)` you add more than 1 item to that row. Didn't you get a runtime exception? Also, `ListBox1.Datasource = dtTest` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code that works.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dtTest As New DataTable
        dtTest.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(Integer))


        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            dtTest.Rows.Add(i)
        Next

        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Col1"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "Col1"

        ListBox1.DataSource = dtTest
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Thanks a ton for that. But the result which I get is numbers from 1 - 10 in the listbox. How do I get the data in my Access (.mdb) database to show up here. I have set up the oledb connection etc..; Table Name: ATG ; Field Name: Term. (Sorry if these are basic questions I'm just a beginner)

Comment: @user823911 - you're now asking a different question: How do I populate a Datatable with records from an Access .mdb table? I'll bet you could find that answer on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\folder\Your File.txt"))
```

Comment: he's reading them from a database so it's definitely not like reading a text file